# Curl does not upload entire file

Tags: curl

I am trying to upload a jar file to AWS codeartifact from a Jenkinsfile, i am trying to follow their [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/maven-curl.html):

```
sh '''
    1)get the authorization token into 'CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN'
    curl -v --request PUT $url --user \"aws:$CODEARTIFACT_AUTH_TOKEN\" --header \'Content-Type: application/octet-stream\' --data-binary $file
'''
```

When i do al `ls -l` i see that the file has size: `20298`
But curl only uploads 169 bytes:

```
17:14:13  > user-agent: curl/7.74.0
17:14:13  > accept: */*
17:14:13  > content-type: application/octet-stream
17:14:13  > content-length: 169
```

How is this possible?

Comment: 169 bytes could be the length of an error message. What is the content of the uploaded file?

Comment: when i download it from codeartifact, is empty